# How to delete multiple id from req.params in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

how to accept req.params that contain multiple id ? I want to search and delete the multiple id

here's my code :

```
const id = req.params;
    
    const masterFunders = await masterFunder.findOne({
      where: {
        id: ids
      }
    })

    if (!masterFunders) {
      return res.API.error(RESPONSE_MESSAGE.file_not_found, 400)
    }

    if (masterFunders.createdAt.getTime() > new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10 * 3)) {
      return res.API.error(RESPONSE_MESSAGE.cannot_delete_file, 400)
    }
    
    await masterFunder.destroy({
      where: { id: ids }
    });

    return res.API.success(RESPONSE_MESSAGE.success, 200)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.API.error(error.message)
```

it's error

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Invalid value {\n  id: '[de7cc75d-4925-4a8d-869c-9072c7310fc9, b9da8552-e3f9-4628-a5a2-9709399b20dc]'\n}",
    "meta": {}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the initialization of the `ids` variable?

Answer (score 0):

"ids" seems to be a string that contains an array in JSON format, **not a JavaScript array.**

So you need to do: `ids = JSON.parse(ids);` to convert the string to a JavaScript array :)